# What is the regulation(s) that states GPS can be used in lieu of DME? Pertaining to the US

Tags: faa-regulations, instrument-flight-rules

I always hear that GPS can be used in lieu of DME, but I would like to know the specific regulation that states this.

Comment: In the U.S.  it is found in the AIM 1-2-3.

Comment: There is no specific FAA regulation that states that GPS can be used in lieu of DME.  There are Advisory Circulars and TSO's that read together provide this authority.

Answer (score 0):

For the US, this is part of [AC 90-108 "*Use of Suitable Area Navigation (RNAV) Systems on Conventional Routes and Procedures*"](https://www.faa.gov/documentLibrary/media/Advisory_Circular/AC_90-108_CHG_1.pdf)

> 7.a: Usage of Suitable RNAV Systems. Subject to the operating requirements in this AC, operators may use a suitable RNAV system in the following ways
>
> (1) Determine aircraft position relative to or distance from a VOR (see first note in subparagraph 7b), TACAN, NDB, compass locator (see second note in subparagraph 7b), DME fix; or a named fix defined by a VOR radial, TACAN course, NDB bearing, or compass locator bearing intersecting a VOR or Localizer (LOC) course.
> (2) Navigate to or from a VOR, TACAN, NDB, or compass locator.
> (3) Hold over a VOR, TACAN, NDB, compass locator, or DME fix.
> (4) Fly an arc based upon DME

Summary on the AOPA site: [Use of GPS in lieu of DME/ADF](https://www.aopa.org/advocacy/advocacy-briefs/air-traffic-services-brief-use-of-gps-in-lieu-of-dme-adf).

Note GNSS in lieu of DME doesn't include approaches, like ILS/DME. In these approaches the DME may be located at any suitable place, e.g. at the mid point of the runway length, and its 50 µs response delay recalibrated to indicate 0 at the threshold of the active runway. Something the GNSS cannot handle without additional information.